# Can we exactly find where is instatenous axis of rotation is of a rod subjected to a constraint?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Suppose we have a rod which is connected with two strings with some angle theta eith vertical , suppose one string is cut out , is it possible to figure out where the IAOR of rod is located at just after the instant string is cut ? (My thought process was that we know point A acceleration direction very well for t= dt moment ,but we dont know centre of mass acceleration exact direction , is it still possible to figure out IAOR ?)[image]

Answer (score 0):

From newtons laws and torque equation we can calculate both centre of mass acceleration and end point acceleration where string is connected , from there we can say in dt time speed would be v1 and v2 , now draw perpendiculars we will get the IAOR of the rod .